# (Dis-)Advantages of Design Space Exploration Frameworks generating MILPs (e.g. DeSyDe, ArchEx, ...)

Tags: mixed-integer-programming

Are there still reasons to create MILPs manually from the ground up, or is it more suitable to rely on certain frameworks translating requirements and elements into proper MILPs using a set of rules, e.g. [example rules](https://www.fico.com/fico-xpress-optimization/docs/latest/mipform/dhtml/chap2s1.html?scroll=ssecabsval).

Those translators/compilers can of course become as sophisticated as necessary with enough work and complex rule sets, I guess, like any compiler.

I stumbled across multiple DSE concepts in publications and was wondering, how do their MILPs actually look like until I noticed they never created MILPs themselves. However, I realized that they never actually constructed MILPs themselves; rather, they input their problems into existing frameworks.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of relying on DSE frameworks automatically deriving MILPs? Is it possible for frameworks allowing a highly complex expressiveness while ensuring the existence of a convex relaxation for resulting MILPs?

Comment: Could you share some examples of "DSE frameworks"?